# PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException using oracle in sprig batch 5

Tags: spring-batch

I am using spring batch 5. I am using oracle database using application.properties. I have have schedule to run the batch every after two minutes.But sometimes it shows below error:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

2024-03-05 09:48:00,160 ERROR com.citylive.eftbatch.config.ScheduledJobBean [scheduling-1] PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID, JOB_INSTANCE_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, VERSION, CREATE_TIME, LAST_UPDATED)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    ]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

**Here is my code**

My application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydb
    spring.datasource.username=test
    spring.datasource.password=test124
    db.name=test

    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=10
    spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=always

    logging.level.root=INFO
    logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=DEBUG
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 2000
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
    spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10
```

My Schedule Run the job:

```
        @Component
    @Slf4j
    public class MyJobJob {
        @Autowired
        JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        EftJob2 eftJob;

        @Autowired
        private  JobRepository jobRepository;

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
        public void perform() throws Exception
        {
            
            JobExecution execution = null;
            JobExecution lastJobExecutionStep1 = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("EFT-STEP1", new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters());
            

            if (lastJobExecutionStep1 == null || lastJobExecutionStep1.getStatus().isLessThan(BatchStatus.STARTING)) {
                log.info( "{}  batch step1 {} execution {} Started: ");
                try {

                    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                            .addLong("startAtEftStep1", System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .toJobParameters();

                    execution = jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(), jobParameters);

                    log.info(" batch {} Step1 existStatus: "+execution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());

                } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException |
                         JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException |
                         JobParametersInvalidException ex) {
                    log.error("batch {} Step1 {} execution {} JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException message: "+ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                

                }
            }else{
                log.info(" batch step1 {} execution {} isRunning: ");
            }

        }
    }
```

Job:

```
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Slf4j
    public class EftJob2 {
        private final MySummaryRepo approvedTrxSummaryRepo;
        private final MyTransactionRepo corpApprovedTransactionRepo;

        private final EftProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
        private final EftWriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;


        private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
        private final JobRepository jobRepository;


        @Autowired
        private JobExecutionListenerStep1 jobExecutionListenerStep1;


        @Autowired
        private MySPcall transactionSPcall;


        public Job createEft(){
            
            return new JobBuilder("EFT-STEP1", jobRepository)
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .start(step1())
                    .listener(jobExecutionListenerStep1)
                    .build();

        }
        

        private Step step1(){

            return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                    .<ApprovedTrxSummery, ApprovedTrxSummery> chunk(10, transactionManager)
                    .reader(new EftReaderStep1(approvedTrxSummaryRepo,corpApprovedTransactionRepo, transactionSPcall))
                    .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                    .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                    .build();
        }


    }
```

Batch config:

```
    @Configuration
    public class BatchBean {
        @Bean
        public EftProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1() {
            return new EftProcessorStep1();
        }

        @Bean
        public EftWriterStep1 batchWriterStep1() {
            return new EftWriterStep1();
        }

    }
```

repository:

```
@Transactional
    @Repository
    public interface TransactionRepo extends JpaRepository<TransactionEntity, Long> {
        @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION WHERE STATUS =1 FOR UPDATE ", nativeQuery = true)
        List<TransactionEntity> getbKashTransaction();
    }
```

Batch Reader:  Read data repository using ItemReader

```
@Slf4j
    public class ReaderStep1 implements ItemReader<TransactionEntity> {
        private Iterator<TransactionEntity> iterator;
        private TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall;
        public ReaderStep1(TransactionRepo transactionRepo, TransactionSPcall transactionSPcall) {
            this.transactionSPcall = transactionSPcall;
           List<TransactionEntity> list = transactionRepo.getbKashTransaction();

            if(!list.isEmpty()){

                this.iterator = list.iterator();
                
            }
        }

        @Override
        public TransactionEntity read() {

            return (iterator != null && iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : null;
        }
    }
```

Batch Processor:

```
@Slf4j
    public class ProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<TransactionEntity, TransactionEntity> {
        @Override
        public TransactionEntity process(TransactionEntity item) throws Exception {
               // Logic calling api

            return item;
        }
```

Batch writer:

```
        @Slf4j
    public class WriterStep1 implements ItemWriter<TransactionEntity> {


        @Override
        public void write(Chunk<? extends TransactionEntity> chunk) {
            
            chunk.forEach(item -> {
              // update database 

            });      
        }
    }
    }
```

I have update all transaction when picked in ItemReader because another batch won't take the data. I am using oracle. There are multiple batch are running using the database. Sometime it happens the error..

How avoid the error?

What is the wrong of my batch configure?

Please help me....